# Statement Where comparando variável Data(tipo date) com data atual

Tags: sql, oracle

Olá. Estou usando SQL do Oracle e preciso de uma query que retorne valores onde a data é igual a data atual.
Oracle tem alguma palavra reservada para data atual no sistema?

Meu código:

```
insert into monitoracao(idseq, idsess, inst_name, elapsed_time, dateTime, fulltextsql, idsql)
SELECT idSeq.nextval,
sess.sid, 
inst.instance_name,
sqla.elapsed_time,
sqla.last_active_time,
sqla.sql_fulltext,
sqla.sql_id
FROM gv$sqlarea sqla, gv$session sess, gv$instance inst
WHERE sess.sql_hash_value = sqla.hash_value
AND sess.sql_address = sqla.address
AND sess.inst_id = inst.inst_id
AND elapsed_time > 10000000
-------------------------------------------------
select inst_name, dateTime 
from monitoracao, gv$sqlarea sqla
where monitoracao.DATETIME = SYSDATE;
```

Comment: o que há de errado na sua consulta? `where monitoracao.DATETIME = SYSDATE` não funciona??

Comment: Eu percebi que no select, está sendo retornado uma data com formato (dia-mes-ano), o SYSDATE retorna esse mesmo formato? ou o formato (mes-dia-ano)?

Comment: Não retorna nada, como se os dados não fossem iguais.

Answer (score 1):

Converte o monitoracao.datetime e sysdate para date e na mesma notação.

```
SELECT inst_name, dateTime 
   FROM monitoracao, gv$sqlarea sqla
   WHERE TO_DATE(monitoracao.DATETIME, 'DD-MM-YYYY') = TO_DATE(SYSDATE, 'DD-
   MM-YYYY');
```

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que seu problema seja que está validando a data completa. Como você quer apenas a data de hoje, faça a comparação formatando as datas para ignorar horas:

```
select inst_name, dateTime 
from monitoracao, gv$sqlarea sqla
where (monitoracao.DATETIME, 'MM-DD-YYYY') = (SYSDATE, 'MM-DD-YYYY');
```

Comment: É, deu errado aqui
ORA-00920: operador relacional inválido

Vou continuar tentando

Answer (score 0):

Bem galera, problema resolvido aqui. Eu não tinha o conhecimento de que SYSDATE (e outras variáveis do tipo DATE)pegava, alem do dia, mes e ano, as Horas, minutos e segundos... Por isso, para conseguir comparar apenas as datas, usei o comando

```
alter session set nls_date_format = 'dd-mm-yyyy'
```